# Maintain grid system across `default.vue` and `index.vue` in vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, css-grid

I am very new to vue, this probably is very basic question. I want a page with 3-col layout, where two columns should be in `default.vue` and the one column should be in a page, say `index.vue`. I have created everything in `default.vue` and it works fine but I can not maintain that when I move the content to `index.vue` file. Here is overview of what I have:

```
<html>
 <body>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          Navigation
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8"> <!-- I need this div in index.vue -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><WelcomeText></WelcomeText></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Card 1</div>
        <div class="col">Card 2</div>
        <div class="col">Card 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <CompanyCard></CompanyCard>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, if I move the whole div including `col-8` to `index.vue` then `CompanyCard` moves to left near the `Navigation` and the main div goes below that. On the other had, if I just keep the line `<div class="col-8">` in `default.vue` and move the content (2 rows inside this) to `index.vue`. The `CompanyCard` remains at right, as it should but the middle column is blank and the content is below that. How do I maintain that 3-col format across `default.vue` and `index.vue` ?

I am using `Nuxt` with `Vuetify`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `Nuxt` then you should use `<Nuxt />` component inside `defualt.vue`. this will include the page component
you can check [nuxt layout docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/layouts/)

example for `default.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"> Navigation </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <!-- I need this div in index.vue -->
            <Nuxt />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">Card 1</div>
                <div class="col">Card 2</div>
                <div class="col">Card 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <CompanyCard></CompanyCard>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

now inide your `index.vue` add:

```html
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><WelcomeText></WelcomeText></div>
    </div>
</template>
```